# How can we use One controllers method in other controllers view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two controllers named: `lists_controller.rb` and `articles_controller.rb`.

And a view under `articles/index.html.rb`.

I want to use a element from `list_controller.rb` in `articles/index.html.rb`.
My method in `lists_controller.rb` is as follows:

```
def index
    @lists = List.all
end
```

I want to use `@lists` in `articles/index.html.rb` to loop over the elements under `@lists` instance in the `articles/index.html.rb` view under `articles_controller.rb`

Comment: You need to define the same in `index` method of `articles_controller` to use `@lists` in `articles/index.html.rb`

Comment: Thank you.I know this is just basic.But cannot get it at right time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to simply add `@lists = List.all` to `ArticlesController#index`. It's hardly enough code to worry about duplication/DRY.

Were more complex behavior required, you can share behavior among controllers by defining it in `ApplicationController` (from which controllers inherit), or among multiple actions within a controller using [filters](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters), or by combining the two.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the title literally - you could create a module with a method called list_index and then include that module in both controllers.

In your particular case it's probably be easier to just have the two calls as others have outlined.